# ApplicationEventPublisher is not being autowired into Component

Tags: spring, hibernate, events, spring-boot, autowired

I have a Spring Boot app and `@Component` class which looks like:

```
@Component
public class CustomEvent {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @PreRemove
    public void onItemDelete(Object entity) {
        System.out.println(" =======PUBLISH====== " + entity);
        publisher.publishEvent(new EntityDeleteEvent<>(entity));
    }
}
```

When it goes to run above method the first line is printed with proper entity but the `publisher.publishEvent` line throws a `NullPointerException`. I suppose it that the `ApplicationEventPublisher` is not being `@Autowired` but couldn't find why. Other `@Components` which are in the app are found by `@ComponentScanner`.

Of course in my entity this `CustomEvent` is registered:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(
        CustomEvent.class
)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Item
```

The exact error which is thrown looks like:

```
2017-10-26 16:46:06.190 ERROR 10176 --- [io-8091-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.inventory.events.CustomEvent.onItemDelete(CustomEvent.java:19)
```

Do you have any suggestion why `publisher` is `null`?

Comment: Is CustomEvent class inside package scan of spring?

Comment: Actually Yeap it is.

Answer (score 2):

The initialisation of `ApplicationEventPublisher` doesn't happen OR will remain null, if you have created the `CustomeEvent` without the help of Bean (like `CustomEvent event = new CustomEvent()`.

Instead, declare the `CustomEvent` as bean in your configuration (Spring) and get the `CustomEvent` using application context.

Answer (score 1):

If `CustomEvent` is in the Spring's package scan, then I don't know.

But, there is an additional solution.

Create a class to instantiate spring managed class, but by **ApplicationContext**.

1 - Create the class below:

```
public class AppContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) throws BeansException {
        context = appContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> classe) {
        return context.getBean(classe);
    }

}
```

2 - Instance class as below:

```
public class CustomEvent {

    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @PreRemove
    public void onItemDelete(Object entity) {
        System.out.println(" =======PUBLISH====== " + entity);
        getApplicationEventPublisher().publishEvent(new EntityDeleteEvent<>(entity));
    }

    private ApplicationEventPublisher getApplicationEventPublisher() {
        return AppContextUtil.getBean(ApplicationEventPublisher.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Implementing `org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisherAware` solved the problem.